# How do I make printf not flush stdout in C?

Tags: c, printf, stdout

In C, normally when I call `printf` it automatically flushes stdout.

How do I stop it from doing that, and just have it put the text into the stdout without actually updating the terminal?

This is probably a duplicate of some question, but I literally just can't find it

Comment: The `stdout` stream, when connected to a terminal or console, will flush automatically on newline. There are functions ([`setbuf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/setbuf), [`setvbuf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/setvbuf)) to change behavior.

Comment: Out of curiosity: can you explain why you actually need that ? It might be a [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: I need it to print repeated text like 4000 times, and have it appear all at once.

Comment: How about building the entire text as a long string, and then `printf`ing it in one go ?

Comment: The string is 6 bytes long, so I'll have to make a 24,000 byte long string, and that's kinda not memory efficient

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add all the relevant info there (including your system and it's limitations). E.g. on typical PCs using 24KB is not something that should usually worry you these days.

Comment: Yeah, but it's still a lot.

Comment: Even on my old Amiga 500 with 512 KiB RAM I wouldn't worry too much about 24 k. A normal PC today, and even phones, you have multiple **giga**bytes of memory. 24 k is nothing. When your data comes into the tens of megabytes range, you might consider some other data-structures and algorithms.

Comment: That 24KB string is going to have to go somewhere in memory if you aren't flushing it. If it's not in your process's memory, it's in the OS's memory. And if it gets too long it will probably get flushed anyway at some point.

Comment: @Verpous brings up a very good point. If you don't want the output to be flushed, it must be buffered somewhere. Now you have to decide where that buffer will be: Under your own control, or somewhere deeper down the system where you have little to no control over it.

Comment: Alright, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the additional info in your comments, I believe it is an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Instead of using `printf` multiple times and forcing it to avoid flushing, you could build your entire text in a long string, and use `printf` once to dump it to the terminal.

You mentioned in the comments that the entire string would be 24K long.

Your concern about using 24KB of memory is not justified IMHO:

1. Typical systems nowadays (including mobile phones) have GBs of memory and using 24KB is quite negligable.
2. As @Verpous [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77880245/how-do-i-make-printf-not-flush-stdout-in-c/77880607#comment137298446_77880245), if you avoid flushing, all the text will have to be stored in memory somewhere anyway.